# VS2012 equivalent of Eclipse's default Ctrl-Shift-O?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm used to Java (in Eclipse), which has its `import` statements, but I'm writing a DLL in Visual C# (in Visual Studio 2012), which has its `using` statements. I'm used to Eclipse's default keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-O, which updates the list of import statements in the Java perspective, deleting unused imports and adding necessary imports found on the build path.

Is there an equivalent operation in VS2012 with VC#? I've just been selecting the word, opening the Office-style popup, and added the "using" statement that way, but it conflicts with my workflow (read: I'm lazy and I like having my shortcuts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is [Organizing Using Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514114%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which you can access from `Edit / IntelliSense / Organize Usings`or by right-clicking in the code editor (it should be the 2nd item from the top I think).

Comment: This is what I ended up using for sorting and deleting usings. It won't add them, but I can deal with that. Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 0):

With your cursor on the method or parameter that needs a using statement press CTRL-. that will open that "Office-style popup" and press enter to select the first item.